# Hide division when focus is lost

Tags: jquery, focus, hide, blur

In the below screenshot you will see a large green rectangle. This division is shown when clicking a "My Account" link. It can then be hidden by clicking a "Hide" image.

**Screenshot:** http://knowwhovotes.com/somecap.JPG

I would like the green division to be hidden if a user clicks anywhere outside of the division. I have tried the blur function but could not get it working properly.

**Here is the code I have already:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_account_button").click(function() {
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'block'});
        $("#my_account").slideDown("Slow");
    });
    $("#hide_account").click(function() {
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'none'});
        $("#my_account").slideUp("Slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "the green division"

Comment: I mean the large(970px x 495px) green division showed in the screenshot

Comment: I think the confusion is that it is not common to call a `div` a division, even though that's what it means.  You mean the popup box div, right?

Comment: @JeffB Yes :) - & thanks for your response, I am implementing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, focus/blur are generally only for `input` elements.  They do not fire for `div` elements.

You need to have the `div` be hidden when you click on the document, **but not** when you click on the `div` itself or anything in it.  To do this, add a click handler to the document, and then stop clicks on the `div` from propagating up the DOM tree, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_account_button").click(function() {
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'block'});
        $("#my_account").slideDown("Slow");
    });
    $("#hide_account").click(function() {
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'none'});
        $("#my_account").slideUp("Slow");
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'none'});
        $("#my_account").slideUp("Slow");
    });
    $("#c_fancy").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

You probably then want to consolidate and put the hide code in a common function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_account_button").click(function() {
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'block'});
        $("#my_account").slideDown("Slow");
    });

    function hideAccount() { 
        $("#c_fancy").css({'display' : 'none'});
        $("#my_account").slideUp("Slow");
    }

    $("#hide_account").click(hideAccount);
    $(document).click(hideAccount);

    $("#c_fancy").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

I do notice that the content behind the `div` is darkened.  This could cause problems if this darkening overlay is part of your `#c_fancy` element.  If so, you need to change your code a bit.  Basically, you would need to change the above code from `$(document)` to `$('#myOverlay')`, substituting `#myOverlay` appropriately of course.